# ComponentDidMount not working

Tags: reactjs

I am adding a user via phone number.

The submit button is disabled until all 10 digits are entered, that works fine. When I click the submit button and try to add a new user with a different phone number, the submit button is enabled until I hit the first key then the button becomes disabled again until the rest of the 9 digits are entered into the field.

When I tried to create a `componentDidMount` function the app completely breaks. Here is a bit of my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dialog, Button, TextField } from 'material-ui'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { inviteAdminByPhone } from '../db'
import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask'
import { phoneNumber } from '../masks'
import SpinnerButton from '../components/spinner-button'
import { CircularProgress } from 'material-ui/Progress'

const byId = id => document.getElementById(id)

class AddManagerModal extends React.Component {
  state = {
    disabled: true,
    phone: ''
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if ({ disabled: false && this.state.phone < 10 }) {
      this.checkPhoneFields()
    }
  }

  handleChange = (name, id) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: document.getElementById(id).value
    })
  }

  PhoneMask = () => {
    return (
      <MaskedInput
        mask={phoneNumber}
        placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
        placeholder="Phone Number"
        id="add-manager-phone"
        className="masked-input"
        onChange={e => {
          this.handleChange('phone', 'add-manager-phone')
          console.log(e.target.value)
          if (e.target.value.replace(/[(.)\s]/g, '').length === 10) {
            this.setState({ disabled: false })
          } else {
            this.setState({ disabled: true })
          }
        }}
      />
    )
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'ADD_MANAGER_MODAL',
      payload: !this.props.open
    })
  }

  checkPhoneFields = () => {
    if (byId('login-phone').value.replace(/[(.)\s]/g, '').length === 10) {
      this.setState({ disabled: false })
      return
    }
    this.setState({ disabled: true })
  }

  render() {
    const props = this.props
    const show = props.show
    const phone = this.state.phone
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog open={props.open} onBackdropClick={() => this.handleOpen()}>
          <div className="dialog-padding max-width-300">
            <h3 className="oswald font-light tal mb0">Managers Phone Number</h3>
            <TextField
              value={phone}
              fullWidth
              className="max-width-250"`enter code here`
              InputProps={{ inputComponent: this.PhoneMask }}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="dialog-padding tar">
            <Button
              variant="flat"
              color="secondary"
              onClick={() => this.handleOpen()}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <SpinnerButton
              id="invite-new-manager"
              variant="raised"
              color="primary"
              disabled={this.state.disabled}
              onClick={() =>
                props.addAdmin(
                  byId('add-manager-phone').value,
                  show.eid,
                  'invite-new-manager'
                )
              }
              label="Invite"
            />
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    open: state.addManagerModal,
    show: state.show
  }
}

const mapActionToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    dispatch,
    addAdmin: (number, event_id, id) =>
      dispatch(inviteAdminByPhone(number, event_id, id))
  }
}

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)

export default connector(AddManagerModal)
```

Comment: Where are error you getting?

Comment: the error in the console says "Cannot read property 'value' of null". Before I added the componentDidUpdate the app was working accept for the issue I mentioned above when adding a new user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like disabled variable doesn't exist. Should it be this.state.disabled? Because I saw you declare one in the constructor.

```
    componentDidUpdate() 
    {
      if ({ disabled: false && this.state.phone < 10 }) 
      {
        this.checkPhoneFields()
      }
    }
```

Comment: add proper tags, It will help your question to reach proper audience

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip. I tried this.state.disabled and it gives me a linter error in by atom, my code editor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize your state in a constructor. This will always initialize the state before any of the lifecycle methods are called. You shouldn't need the `componentDidMount` call then.

Comment: Thank you for the input I entered the following code below and it still didn't work                                                                           constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { disabled: false }
    {
      this.checkPhoneFields()
    }
  }

Comment: Does this component remount every time you add a new phone number?

Comment: After the 10th digit is added for the first new user, the submitt button becomes clickable. When I go to add a second new user the  submit button is clickable, until I I began to type the numbers and then the button is disabled until the 10th digit is typed.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm wondering if the modal is removed from the DOM when you click the submit button. It does not look like it does. So I would reset the disabled state to true when you click submit. I'm also curious why you're not storing the value of your phone number in the component state?

Comment: I tried what you suggested and its still not working. Maybe I am resetting  the disabled state true in the wrong spot? I am not sure how I would go about storing the number in the component state if I have the potential of gaining numerous numbers. Can you explain?

Comment: What do you mean by "gaining numerous numbers"? Can I see what state it's in now and what the error message looks like?

Comment: There isn't really much of an error in the console browser. It just says InvalidValueError: not an Instance of HTMLInput Element. How can I go about showing you the state im in now? Do you want to see the code?

Answer (score 0):

Propably you're getting this error, because `byId` cannot find requested element (with id "login-phone") and returns `null`.

Change condition in `componentDidUpdate`, because object is resolved to `true` when it's converted to boolean.

```js
if ({}){
  console.log("Condition satisfied");
}

if ({disabled: false}){
  console.log("This one too");
}
```

I think you need something like:

```
componentDidUpdate() 
{
  if (!this.state.disabled && this.state.phone < 10 ) 
  {
    this.checkPhoneFields()
  }
}
```

or (in case when `this.state.phone` is string and you need to check its length):

```
componentDidUpdate() 
{
  if (!this.state.disabled && this.state.phone && this.state.phone.length < 10 ) 
  {
    this.checkPhoneFields()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help barbsan, I tried both and neither seem to do the trick.

Comment: Have you check also whether `byId` finds element with id "login-phone"?

Comment: This is a bit new to me can you elaborate please?

Comment: In `checkPhoneFields` you've got this line: `if (byId('login-phone').value.replace(/[(.)\s]/g, '').length === 10) {`. If there's no element with id "login-phone" then `byId` will return `null` and hence you're trying to access property `value` of `null`

Comment: so you are saying I need to include the id "login-phone" into the componenetDidMount? I am sorry i am not getting it, as I mentioned I am fairly new to this and I want to make sure I get a good grasp on everything.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly the code would look something like this   componentDidUpdate() {
    if (byId('login-phone')({ disabled: false && this.state.phone < 10 })) {
      this.checkPhoneFields()
    }
  }

Comment: No, condition in `componentDidUpdate` and that problem with element are two different things. In component update you're calling `this.checkPhoneFields()` in which you're looking for html element with id "login-phone" but I can't see in your code element with that id - is it somewhere else in your code?